# CSRF TOKEN and cookies having JESSION ID are not passed to different scenario in the karate

Tags: karate

Scenario 1:

```
url: path1

Method : POST

Headers     
Accept
Content-Type


Form fields:
Username
Password

url: path2
Method:get

Headers     
Accept
Content-Type
```

Output of path2 is `CSRF TOKEN` and cookies having `JESSION ID`

Scenario2:
For calling any path in scenario 2 we need to pass the path2 outputs which is `CXRF TOKEN` and `JSESSIONID`

Problem:

For our test cases we need to always pass the jsession id(this jession id should be taken from the path2 only) and csrf token from path2 to all the subsequent calls. Which is not happening now

> 1>Csrf token is not getting passed to scenario2
>
> 2>JESSION ID created here is different from the jesession id from path2

Wants to know if there is way to pass this csrf token and jesession id headers to different scenario please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read the doc and then look at these particular examples: [call-updates-config.feature](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/call-updates-config.feature) and [common.feature](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/common.feature)

Here's what I would do:

- try to get everything working as a SINGLE scenario first before proceeding further. normally you never need to set cookies manually
- write a re-usable feature that makes the calls to `path1` and `path2` and keep that in `common.feature`.
- at the end of `common.feature` set the values of the CSRF token and JSESSIONID to variables
- now you can write a second feature or scenario that calls `common.feature`. again, please read the docs, there are so many examples on how to call one feature from another and pass variables
- as I said, you normally don't need to do anything to cookies, but you should be able to set the cookie like this (refer syntax for `cookie`): `* cookie JSESSIONID = yourVariableName`
- similarly use the `header` keyword or whichever is appropriate for setting the CSRF token correctly

Comment: Hi Peter,  The solution worked perfectly fine for me. Thank you for quick response :)