# In Karate how do I send response cookie from one request in another request

Tags: api, automation, session-cookies, karate, response-headers

I am trying to use the response cookie from a previous response in another request. From the code snip below, I want to set the cookie using the 'name' and 'value' as cookie in the next request

'''
14:11:38.731 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "JSESSIONID": {
    "name": "JSESSIONID",
    "value": "791Unpfkb79400z6S-yL-Sl5.node1",
    "domain": "localhost",
    "path": "/path",
    "persistent": "false",
    "secure": "false"
  }
'''

Answer (score 0):

Normally you never need to do anything "extra" - and Karate will automatically use cookies returned in the next request, please refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#cookie

That said, refer to this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49852441/143475